# Enthought canopy update (1.4 to 1.6) erased ALL my projects any way to restore?

Tags: python, enthought, canopy

I have updated canopy from 1.4 to 1.6 and poof all my projects everything is gone. I guess they were somehow embedded into the canopy package itself but not on an address in my PC and I was careless enough to worry about that. Any way to restore the lost data or anyone has even experienced this problem ?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Sorry for the trouble. Please be very specific about what was erased -- the exact path to the files which you think are missing. Uninstalling or installing Canopy does not even touch the User Python environment into which packages are installed, and it certainly does not touch your source directories, unless you put your source files in the middle of the Canopy application installation, which would be quite inappropriate.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer and sorry for the late response. I guess I am at least partially guilty for not heeding where the files I created were saved. I can't check where it was now because I saved the last file to documents thus this is the default location. Somehow the previous default location must have been somewhere inappropriate as you said